# The cURL executable has stopped

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

When I try to put any data in elastic search I am getting error like:
**The cURL executable has stopped** 
Window popup comes up and gives error.

C:\elasticsearch-1.1.1\bin>curl –XPUT "//localhost:9200/api/twittervnext/tweet”

Can anybody help me solving above issue.

Comment: Could you please post all the available details related to the error message that you are seeing?

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: curl.exe
  Application Version: 7.36.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 53440781
  Fault Module Name: curl.exe

Comment: Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt